# ruby search and replace with readlines

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to collect an array of numbers from each line that matches a certain pattern within a file.  There is only 1 number per line but not all lines have a number (I want to reject those lines).  I am able to do this using two array operations but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner method.

```
lines = []
File.open(myfile, "r") do |file|
  lines = file.readlines.select{|line| line =~ /^ *'(p_)*\d+'/}
end
nums  = lines.collect{|line| line.chomp.sub(/^ *\'(p_)*(\d+)\'.*/, '\2').to_i}
```

I have tried `nums = file.readlines.collect{|line| line.chomp.sub(/^ *\'(p_)*(\d+)\'.*/, '\2').to_i}` but that inserts a zero into my array for any lines that don't match the pattern.    Is it possible to do a search-and-replace and only return lines that match the search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nums = File.open(myfile, 'r').read.split("\n")
  .map { |line| line.chomp.sub(/^ *\'(p_)*(\d+)\'.*/, '\2').to_i }
  .reject(&:zero?)
```

Comment: That works for my specific case but what if some of the numbers I want to grab are zero?

Comment: GregRuhl, if zero is a valid result, then you can replace the `reject` with your `select` pattern matcher, before the `map` statement.